WIC metadata enumeration lost some blocks/items
I use the following code to dump metadata(frame level, not container level) tree. When running it for png files, it loses a lot of blocks/items. Is there anything wrong? My sample code only print each meta item value's type to make it clear.
main.cc
#include <wincodec.h>

#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>

void PrintMetadata(IWICMetadataQueryReader* query_reader, int32_t indentation) {
  IEnumString* enumerator{};
  if (FAILED(query_reader->GetEnumerator(&enumerator))) {
    return;
  }

  while (true) {
    LPOLESTR name{};
    ULONG fetched{};
    if (enumerator->Next(1, &name, &fetched) == S_OK) {
      PROPVARIANT var;
      ::PropVariantInit(&var);
      if (query_reader->GetMetadataByName(name, &var) == S_OK) {
        std::wcout << std::wstring(indentation, L'\t') << name;
        if (var.vt == VT_UNKNOWN) {
          std::wcout << std::endl;
          IWICMetadataQueryReader* sub_query_reader{};
          if (SUCCEEDED(var.punkVal->QueryInterface(&sub_query_reader))) {
            PrintMetadata(sub_query_reader, indentation + 1);
            sub_query_reader->Release();
          }
        } else {
          std::wcout << " type: " << var.vt;
        }
        std::wcout << std::endl;
      }
      ::PropVariantClear(&var);
      ::CoTaskMemFree(name);
    } else {
      break;
    }
  }

  enumerator->Release();
}

void DumpMetadatas(PCWSTR path) {
  IWICImagingFactory* factory{};
  HRESULT result =
      ::CoCreateInstance(CLSID_WICImagingFactory, nullptr, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
                         __uuidof(IWICImagingFactory), (void**)&factory);
  if (FAILED(result)) {
    return;
  }

  IWICBitmapDecoder* decoder{};
  result = factory->CreateDecoderFromFilename(
      path, nullptr, GENERIC_READ,
      WICDecodeOptions::WICDecodeMetadataCacheOnLoad, &decoder);
  if (FAILED(result)) {
    factory->Release();
    return;
  }

  IWICBitmapFrameDecode* frame{};
  result = decoder->GetFrame(0, &frame);
  if (FAILED(result)) {
    decoder->Release();
    factory->Release();
    return;
  }

  IWICMetadataQueryReader* query_reader{};
  result = frame->GetMetadataQueryReader(&query_reader);
  if (FAILED(result)) {
    frame->Release();
    decoder->Release();
    factory->Release();
    return;
  }

  PrintMetadata(query_reader, 0);
  query_reader->Release();

  frame->Release();
  decoder->Release();
  factory->Release();
}

int wmain(int /*argc*/, wchar_t** argv) {
  ::CoInitializeEx(nullptr, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);

  DumpMetadatas(argv[1]);

  ::CoUninitialize();

  return 0;
}


My code output:
/sRGB
        /RenderingIntent type: 17
/gAMA
        /ImageGamma type: 19

OS and 3rd tools can show lots of information from metadata of the same png files:
ExifTool output:
ExifTool Version Number : 12.98
File Name : red.png
Directory : C:/images
File Size : 1147 bytes
File Modification Date/Time : 2024:10:08 15:06:37+08:00
File Access Date/Time : 2024:10:10 16:05:36+08:00
File Creation Date/Time : 2024:10:08 15:06:37+08:00
File Permissions : -rw-rw-rw-
File Type : PNG
File Type Extension : png
MIME Type : image/png
Image Width : 400
Image Height : 300
Bit Depth : 8
Color Type : RGB with Alpha
Compression : Deflate/Inflate
Filter : Adaptive
Interlace : Noninterlaced
SRGB Rendering : Perceptual
Gamma : 2.2
Pixels Per Unit X : 4724
Pixels Per Unit Y : 4724
Pixel Units : meters
Image Size : 400x300
Megapixels : 0.120


Do you have a sample file?

I post a main.cc file that can be build and run.

Sorry, I meant the sample image file that corresponds to your test

I don't think it's about any special png file. I tried png files created by mspaint, downloaded from internet, the results were nearly the same.

In the list of information you output, most of it is not present in metadata (name, size, pixels, dates, type, width, height, color type, interlaced) so it's normal you don't get it with WIC, or anything else reading metadata. Try some file with real metadata (ex: https://www.iptc.org/std-dev/photometadata/examples/google-licensable/images/IPTC-GoogleImgSrcPmd_testimg01.jpg) and you'll see WIC reads it
